# Lightning Experience: Using custom labels inside HTML Editor

Tags: community, lightning-experience, html, lightning-community, customlabel

I have a **Salesfoce Community** and I wonder if is it possible using **custom labels** inside an **HTML Editor** component (Community Builder).

I've tried it but the customlabel is not being compiled.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can say, HTML Editor is meant to use only "static" contents. And that Custom Label get substituted at run time, don't think you will be able to achieve this within HTML Editor. There are only a set of tags and attributes those are supported by an HTML Editor, which you can find in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_html_editor.htm).